# Impossible to display the data after a get request react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

i'm trying to display information of a restaurant in my react-native app after i get it by a get request from my database. I don't have problem getting the data, it's the display the problem.

Inside my component RestaurantDetailScreen :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getRestaurantInfo()
  }

  getRestaurantInfo = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${environment.apiDevUrl}/restaurant/${this.state.restaurantId}`,
      })
      this.setState({
        restaurantInfo: res.data,
      })
      console.log(this.state.restaurantInfo.restaurant.nom);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

The console log display my state with correct data from my backend, but when I try to render it inside my Flatlist there is nothing to display:

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        {/* <Text>{this.state.restaurantInfo.restaurant.nom}</Text> */}
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.restaurantInfo}
          renderItem={this.renderRestaurantInfo}
          keyExtractor={item => `${item.restaurant.id}`}
        />
        <SectionList
          sections={productData}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          renderItem={this.renderRestaurantDetail}
          renderSectionHeader={({section: {header}}) => (
            <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{header}</Text>
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.id}` + index}
          ref={ref => (this.sectionListRef = ref)}
          getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
        />
      </ScrollView>
```

So i've tried to simply display the name of a restaurant inside a Text component like in the `getRestaurantInfo()` method but it will return a undefined if i don't remove it.

The render method `renderRestaurantInfo()` :

```
  renderRestaurantInfo = ({item}) => (
    <View style={styles.containerRestaurantInfo}>
      {console.log('item : ', item)}
      <ItemRestaurantInfo
        // image={item.restaurant.image}
        title={item.restaurant.nom}
        description={item.restaurant.description}
        categories={item.restaurant.categorie}
        adress={item.restaurant.adresse.rue1}
        scheduleBeginning={item.restaurant.horaires.crenaux.hDebut}
        scheduleEnd={item.restaurant.horaires.crenaux.hFin}
      />
    </View>
  )
```

And finally the `ItemRestaurantInfo` component :

```
ItemRestaurantInfo = ({
  image,
  title,
  categories,
  adress,
  description,
  scheduleBeginning,
  scheduleEnd,
}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {/* <Image source={image} style={styles.topImage} /> */}
      <View style={{padding: 15}}>
        <Text style={styles.restaurantTitle}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.restaurantInfoText}>{`${categories}`}</Text>
        <View style={styles.viewInRow}>
          <Image
            style={{margin: 5}}
            source={require('../../assets/icons/map-pin.png')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.restaurantInfoText}>{adress}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.restaurantInfoText}>{description}</Text>
        <View style={styles.viewInRow}>
          <Image
            style={{margin: 5}}
            source={require('../../assets/icons/calendar.png')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.restaurantInfoText}>{scheduleBeginning} - {scheduleEnd}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to pass `item` in your FlatList [renderItem](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist/#renderitem):

```js
<FlatList
   data={this.state.restaurantInfo}
   renderItem={({item}) => this.renderRestaurantInfo(item)}
   ...
/>
```

You could also return a Component instead of method:

```js
const RenderItems = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

...

// Pass the component to your FlatList
<FlatList
   data={YOURDATA}
   renderItem={({ item }) => <RenderItems title={item.title} />}
   ...
/>
```

And same thing goes for your [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#example)

---

**Edit:** Working [condeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-smoke-8p7wf) example with data fetch.

Comment: Ok but in another component I haven't use the ({item}) => this.renderRestaurantInfo(item) syntax and i can still render my data in the front, for example :

`<FlatList
            initialNumToRender={2}
            data={this.state.restaurantData}
            renderItem={this.renderRestaurantItem}
            keyExtractor={item => `${item.id}`}
     />`

Comment: I have also add what you say but i still haven't any data displayed.

Comment: Please take a look at the official [example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist/#basic-example)

Comment: Here is a [codeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-lake-wfnh7) example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time but i have tried with your code and it's still not working, what is strange it's that it was working with hardcoded value and without the (item) => this.renderRestaurantInfo(item), but now that my data come from by backend i have nothing displayed. I have checked that my state `restaurantInfo: []` is correctly populated and there is no problem, all my data are correctly stored but when the time come to display it nothing show...

Comment: This is weird, maybe restart the server? I made you another example with data fetch please take a look. Could you add a minimal example at codesandbox? you can fork mine.

Comment: Ok I think I have found the problem, when my restaurantInfo array is populated, it transform in an object because there is only one element to display.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have finally find the solution, it was because my array restaurantInfo in the state was transform in an object when I use setState in the call of my backend... so inside the render method of the flatList there was no data.

**OLD CODE**

```
getRestaurantInfo = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${environment.apiDevUrl}/restaurant/${this.state.restaurantId}`,
      }) 
      this.setState({
        restaurantInfo: res.data,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

**NEW CODE**

```
 getRestaurantInfo = async () => {
    try {
      let res = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: `${environment.apiDevUrl}/restaurant/${this.state.restaurantId}`,
      })
      let newArray = [...this.state.restaurantInfo];
      newArray[0] = res.data
      this.setState({
        restaurantInfo: newArray,
      })
      console.log('state dans getResturantinfo:',this.state.restaurantInfo);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

With this syntax it force react to keep an array. And finally it was not necessery to use this syntax : `renderItem={({item}) => this.renderRestaurantInfo(item)}`

In my code I keep it like this :

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state.restaurantInfo}
          renderItem={this.renderRestaurantInfo}
          keyExtractor={item => `${item.restaurant.id}`}
        />
```